# Static assert on methods if class was created by special ctor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class `Foo` which has 2 ctors: default one and parametrized. My class also has two methods: `foo` and `bar`. `foo` is valid for calling on any instance of the class, and `bar` is valid for calling only if the object was created by parametrized ctor.

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(int a) { ... }

    void foo() { ... }
    void bar() { ... }
};
```

I want only `foo` method will be available if class was created by default ctor, and `foo` and `bar` will be available if class was created by the second ctor.

I can do it by creating some class internal-state variable (say, `_state`) which will be initialized in both ctors and which will indicate, what ctor was called

```cpp
Foo::Foo() {
    _state = 1;
}

Foo::Foo(int a) {
    _state = 2;
}
```

Using this variable I can check in runtime which one class ctor was used inside `foo` and `bar` functions:

```cpp
void Foo::bar() {
    if (_state != 2) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Use another ctor");
    }
}
```

Since it is known which ctor was used at compile time, is there any way to also perform such checks on calling methods which will cause an error on compile time, if not right one ctor was used?

Comment: You know "at compile time" which constructor was called, ***in that constructor***. If a method of this class is called from code that's called from some other `.cpp` file, that's compiled separately, for an object that was constructed in a third `.cpp` file, how do you propose that the second `.cpp` file, that's compiled separately, could know how the object was constructed? Sorry, but C++ simply does not work this way.

Comment: If the class that is initialized with the parametrized constructor _is a_ `Foo`, it could inherit from `Foo` instead and only put `bar()` in that class. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/bv9P9oM7x)

Comment: Thanks for answering!